# Can I count rows across multiple pages of a table with robot framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am quite new to robot, and have only been working solo on it at work for a month or so.

Currently I am trying to count the total number on rows in a table within the application I am testing. (chrome based)

This is what I am using:

```
${count}=  get element count  //table[@class='options-table']/tbody/tr
```

Which brings back a value of 5 - this is counting the first page. However, I'm expecting it to bring back 76 as there are multiple pages.

Can anyone help on how to bring back the amount of rows across multiple pages?

```
${count}=  get element count  //table[@class='options-table']/tbody/tr
```

> Expected result: 76
>
> Actual result:  5 (only the first page)

Comment: Any browser tool is only going to be able to see what is on the current page. You will have to navigate forward to all pages and count rows on each page if you want to get the total across all pages.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid a slightly complex logic (iterating through pages, summing up element counts) in a Robot Framework keyword you could [write your own keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#getting-active-library-instance-from-robot-framework) in Python for example.

In this case you need a keyword that takes an element `locator` (`//table[@class='options-table']/tbody/tr` to be specific) and a list of `page urls`.

To implement such keyword, create a file like `ExtendedSeleniumLib.py`:

```python
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def get_element_count_from_pages(locator, *page_urls):
    seleniumlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')

    element_count = 0

    for url in page_urls:
        seleniumlib.go_to(url)
        element_count += seleniumlib.get_element_count(locator)

    return element_count
```

and from your test code you can use it like:

```python
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     ExtendedSeleniumLib

*** Variables ***
${SE HEADER LOCATOR}    //a[@class='site-header--link fs-headline1 fw-bold']

*** Test Cases ***
Count Elements On Multiple Pages Example
    [Setup]    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com    Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed      0.1

    ${count}=   Get Element Count From Pages    ${SE HEADER LOCATOR}
    ...    https://iot.stackexchange.com/
    ...    https://sqa.stackexchange.com/
    ...    https://robotics.stackexchange.com/

    Should Be Equal As Integers     ${count}    3

    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

This example iterates through three Stack Exchange sites and counts the header elements. As there should be only one on each page the expected result is 3. Based on this you should be able to count the table rows on your pages.

About how to configure search path for libraries and resources, check the relevant chapter form the Robot Framework User Guide; [Configuring where to search libraries and other extensions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#module-search-path). If you place the python file into the same directory where your robot file is, then you do not need anything to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code, it assumes that the total number of pages will not be more than 100 since I'm not aware of the webpage, you can either take this number from webpage if available. Also, if you are sure that total number of rows per page is always 5 then you can use below formula
[ 5 * (total number of pages - 1 ) + row count of the last page] 
This can give you total row count across all pages without traversing through all the pages. Also, please add any time synchronisation steps for the successful run.

```
Get Count of All Pages
    ${next_page_locator}    Set Variable    enter next page icon/link xpath here
    ${first_row_locator}    Set Variable    enter first row xpath here
    ${total_count}    set variable    0
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    100
    \    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${first_row_locator}
    \    ${count}    get element count    //table[@class='options-table']/tbody/tr
    \    ${total_count}    evaluate    ${count} + ${total_count}
    \    ${next_link_present}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element    ${next_page_locator}
    \    exit for loop if    ${next_link_present} is ${False}
    \    Click Element    ${next_page_locator}
```